# Recover plain text from a string which is a result of base64 decoding a plain text itself

Tags: php, ajax, encoding, base64, decoding

I made an ajax request to my server and sent some data(plain text) as a query string variable. I saved that data into a text file after using base64_decode() function in php which obviously saves gibberish.

Now I want to recover the plain text from the gibberish data saved in my text file.  How do I do that?

Any help appreciated
test.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
data = '12345';
$.ajax({url:'sample.php?data='+data,success:function(){}});
</script>
```

sample.php

```
<?php

file_put_contents('file.txt','data='.base64_decode($_REQUEST['data'])."\r    \n",FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

Comment: `base64_encode`?

Comment: I decoded the plain text. Not encoded anything

Comment: original data -> base64_decode -> new data -> base64_encode  -> original data

Comment: Make sure you're explicit with your character encoding on both the encode and decode operations.

Comment: @Musa encoding the new data doesnt return the original data

Comment: Let's see some code, example data etc

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: You have an example data set as `12345` which in not base64 encoded, so why are you decoding it?

Comment: See. I accidentally decoded the plain text. But now I want to recover that text from the gibberish data that got saved in my text fle